# Custom WordPress Plugin - Create A FE Page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to create a custom plugin that adds a frontend page to the site. I have figured out how to have WordPress create the pages to the DB when the plugin is activated, but that gives the user the ability to delete them so I would like to create them sort of like adding a static page in the theme, but within a plugin.

I have found this article that shows how to use parameters to display a page, but I would rather have it be a specific slug, not a parameter: https://opensynergic.com/make-custom-plugin-front-end-page-in-wordpress/

Any assistance or direction would be amazing!

Thanks!

Comment: I do not mean to be an a hole.  I suggest you forget WP exists.  Learn HTML, CSS, PHP, and JavaScript and write your own code.   WP will warp your mind.  In PHP you should NEVER switch between PHP and HTML mode.  In a PHP script there should be only one `<?php` at the very  top and one `?>`  at the bottom. No, none, nada exceptions.

Comment: @Misunderstood, I appreciate your input. I do agree, that building custom applications outside of WP can be much easier and more sustainable, but not for all instances. For example, I am working on building a client dashboard that I would like to build into a plugin to use on multiple WP sites for different clients. For this project, I don't have a choice.

Comment: That's okay.  Just please never suggest WP to a potential client.   But I understand WP is a huge market. And it needs all the help it can get.  As a plug in, be sure that any CSS, fonts, or JS are loaded at the top of the <head>.  So many plug-ins make a request for CSS, fonts,  or JS after the page has begun to render.  This causes the Browser to  clear everything and start rendering all over again.